# Sqoop, export HDFS to MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

I'm trying to export from HDFS into MySql and have only been able to find the following technique:

```
public static boolean exportHDFSToSQL() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
         SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
         options.setConnectString("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName");
         options.setUsername("user_name");
         options.setPassword("pwd");
         options.setExportDir("path of file to be exported from hdfs");
         options.setTableName("table_name");
         options.setInputFieldsTerminatedBy(',');
         options.setNumMappers(1);
         new ExportTool().run(options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem I have is with the ExportTool().run() method.  I am using Sqoop 1.4.2 and this method has apparently been deprecated.  Wanting to know the new way of achieving this? Or point me to a documented source that will assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop currently do not exposes any Java API and thus such usage is not supported. It might work, however future versions might break this behavior.

I would expect that you see the deprecation because you are using ExportTool class from package com.cloudera.sqoop.tool, whereas the functionality was moved to package org.apache.sqoop.tool and the original instance was left there for backward compatibility. You can learn more about the namespace migration on [appropriate Sqoop wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SQOOP/Namespace+Migration).